# sql query case statement multiple criteria

Tags: sql

I have a table named SurveyResponse that has the following columns

```
    Id                         int, not null
    SurveyId                   int, not null
    QuestionId                 int, not null
    Response                   varchar, null
    QuestionPossibleAnswerId   int, null
```

The survey table has the following columns

```
    Id              int, not null
    SurveyTypeId    int, not null
    CountyId        int, not null
```

We store the possible answers in a table so the survey creates itself dynamically.  Some questions have a text box where they can type in a response, since only some questions have the text box, the response field is nullable.

I need to get the Responses where SurveyTypeId = 3 (3 is the current year survey)
and Response is not null and QuestionId = 6 (I need the comments for question 6).

The part I'm having problems with is I only want those results where for QuestionId = 24 the QuestionPossibleAnswerId = 111.  Question 24 asks if we can share the results and QuestionPossibleAnswerId 111 is the answer yes.

```
    select sr.Response, 
    (SELECT qpa1.PossibleAnswerText
    FROM    QuestionPossibleAnswer AS qpa1 INNER JOIN
            SurveyResponse AS sr1 ON qpa1.Id = sr1.QuestionPossibleAnswerId
    WHERE        (sr1.QuestionId = 1) AND (sr1.SurveyId = sr.SurveyId)) AS County
    FROM            SurveyResponse AS sr 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN QuestionPossibleAnswer AS qpa ON sr.QuestionPossibleAnswerId =     qpa.Id 
    INNER JOIN Survey AS s ON sr.SurveyId = s.Id 
    INNER JOIN SurveyType AS st ON s.SurveyTypeId = st.Id
    WHERE (sr.Response IS NOT NULL) AND (sr.QuestionId = 6) AND (st.Id = 3)
    ORDER BY County
```

That gives me the Response and County name for question 6, but I need to filter where case QuestionId = 24 AND QuestionPossibleAnswerId = 111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a where exists.

```
and exists(select 1 from SurveyResponse SR2 where QuestionId = 24 and 
QuestionPossibleAnswerId = 111 and SR2.SurveyId = s.Id)
```

This will check if there is a QuestionId = 24 AND QuestionPossibleAnswerId = 111 for the survey you are currently considering.